# Перемещение wpf-контролов из одного AppDomain в другой

Tags: c#, wpf, appdomain

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь разобраться с add-in приложением. Хочу сделать маленькое приложение на плагинах. Изолируя каждый add-in в новый AppDomain. Загружаю wpf-контролы через:

```
FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter  
FrameworkElementAdapters.ContractToViewAdapter
```

но при  AppDomain.unload() память не выгружается (и при закрытии приложение падает ошибка: Конечный домен приложения выгружен), наверно где-то остаётся связь. Если плагин делать без wpf-контрола, то всё нормально - память выгружается и при закрытии приложения ошибок нет.

Вопрос: как правильно загружать wpf-контролы из одного AppDomain в другой?

PS: не используя AddInStore из framework System.AddIn

Answer (score 1):

У вас не только не получится использовать контролы из другого домена, у вас даже не получится использовать контролы из другого потока. Нельзя.

Странно, что у вас приложение не упало при попытке использовать контрол из чужого домена.

Если вам действительно нужен отдельный домен (а скорее всего это не так), держите в нём только модель, а остальное обязано быть в основном домене. А лучше грузите всё в один домен и вместо велосипеда используйте MEF или Prism.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb384200.aspx с помощью MAF можно, но я хотел попробовать не используя AddInStore, всё хорошо работает но при выгрузки AppDomain  память не выгружается и на закрытие приложения падает ошибка на: Конечный домен приложения выгружен - гдето наверно осталась связь - я хотел понять почему и как это исправить... да велосипед изобретать конечно не хорошо но так лучше понять ))